# Abrir, ler e gravar csv

Tags: c

Eu tenho um código em C que está usando a estrutura base para leitura.

**Ler**

```
FILE *input;
input=fopen(argv[1],"r");
points=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point)*num_points);
readPoints(input,points,num_points);
fclose(input);
```

**Gravar**

```
FILE* output=fopen(argv[2],"w");
fprintf(output,"%d\n",num_clusters);
fprintf(output,"%d\n",num_points);
fclose(output);
```

A minha dúvida é como eu posso ler um arquivo csv de maneira que eu não saiba a quantidade de linhas que o mesmo possua e, após isso, gravar os dados em outro arquivo csv.
Seria o mesmo procedimento de C com EOF/!EOF e o código do jeito que eu fiz, ou irá ser feito de maneira diferente?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A função `int feof(FILE *)`, declarada em `stdio.h`, retorna 0 caso o arquivo ainda tenha *bytes* a ler, e 1 caso tenha encontrado o fim do arquivo. Com isso, você consegue executar um laço e transcrever o CSV:

```
FILE * input, * output;
char buffer[2048];
input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
while (! feof(input)) {
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input);
    tratar(buffer); /* esta função vai executar algum tratamento arbitrário na linha */
    fputs(buffer, output);
}
fclose(input);
fclose(output);
```